# Find all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

- Find all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

We showed these claims:

*Claim1.* $f(0)=0$.

*Claim2.* $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

But, how should I show that there is no other $g$ function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ which satisfies

$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Every positive integer is a sum of 1's.

Comment: How will I use the hint?

Comment: Let $d = f(1)$.  What is $f(2) = f(1 + 1)$, for example?

Comment: More generally, how does $f(n)$ depend on $d$, for any integer $n$?

Comment: f(n)=f(1+1+...+1) as n-times 1. Hence, f(n)=nf(1).

Comment: And $f(1)$ is just a fixed, integer (depending on $f$), so what can you say about the types of functions $f$ which have this "linear" property?

Comment: But, this is claim2 and we showed. My question is '' there is no other $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ which satisfies $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70137/discussion-between-benjamin-tighe-and-kahler).